# How was invented quadratic equation?

Tags: elementary-algebra, algebra

How actually people invented the quadratic equation? What practical problem did they solve?
There are some info about this exist in internet, but it is very abstract - I cant find the concrete task which they try to solve. Also I can`t find the way of they thought during solve of that concrete problem.

Comment: See [History of quadratic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#History) for the Babylonian origin.

Comment: Mauro, did you read you link? There are wrote that "Babylonian solve problems relating the areas and sides of rectangles". It is general phrase that nothing clarify. What problem did they try to solve in their usual life? It is what I asked.

Comment: ["finding the dimensions of a rectangle given its area and the amount by which the length exceeds the width"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_mathematics#Algebra) is a "concrete problem" for a society based on agricolture.

Comment: Mauro, ok so for what purposes they need to find the dimensions of a rectangle gives its area? Was there some practical reasons (what reason?) to do that or they solve the equation just for fun?

Comment: We have reasons to believe that math in ancient time originated **not** from "practical needs". See [Abraham Seidenberg](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Seidenberg.html)'s studies : [The ritual origin of geometry](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00327767) (1961) and [The ritual origin of counting](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00325159) (1962) and [The ritual origin of the circle and square](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01395658) (1981).